# Keep connectionId with SignalR 1.0

Tags: refresh, signalr

How can I keep `ConnectionId` when the page refreshes? The `IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator` is not found. I saved a cookie (which contains `ConnectionId`) on the client side. Where should I put it?

I have method:

```
public void Connect(string username, string password, string xmppDomain)
{
    XmppClient xmppClient = XmppClients[Context.ConnectionId];

    xmppClient.Username = username;
    xmppClient.Password = password;
    xmppClient.XmppDomain = xmppDomain;
    xmppClient.Status = "Online";
    xmppClient.Open();
}
```

Can I use this code to put saved connectionid to `Context.ConnectionId`?

```
HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ConnectionId"];
Context.ConnectionId = myCookie.ToString();
```

Also I have jQuery code, which calls every page's refresh:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    matrixHub.server.connect(xmpp_user, xmpp_password, xmpp_host);
});
```

How to modify this code and use persistent `ConnectionId`? I use Matrix XMPP SDK, ASP.NET MVC C# and IIS.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh a page, the existing connection is disconnected and a new one is established with a **new connection id**. This behavior cannot be changed. Saving the connection id in a cookie will not help since the server forgets about a connection once it is disconnected. You should use the session management mechanism in ASP.NET MVC or your custom cookies to associate your users to connection ids.